# Правильно ли стоят тире?

Tags: стилистика

Местные здесь бывают, но иностранцы – редко. Храмовые постройки – небольшие,
вытянутой, как огурец, формы.

Answer (score 1):

Тире поставлены верно. Тире ставится в неполном предложении, составляющем часть сложного предложения, когда пропущенный член (обычно сказуемое) восстанавливается из предыдущей части фразы и в месте пропуска делается пауза: **Местные здесь бывают, но иностранцы – редко.** В этом примере тире стоит на месте пропуска сказуемого **"бывают",** которое восстанавливается из предшествующего контекста. При отсутствии паузы в месте пропуска члена предложения тире не ставится.

Во втором примере тире стоит перед однородными сказуемыми. Храмовые постройки – **небольшие, вытянутой, как огурец, формы.** Ср.: Сын у нее — **желтый, длинный и в очках (М. Г.).**

См.: Полный академический справочник под редакцией Лопатина.